# Gatsby: why does site render differently for local server vs production build?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to create a React site with Gatsby using one of the starter templates. I've heavily customized the Gatsby starter. I have a handful of private routes which I am restricting to logged in users. These internal pages seem to render perfectly on the local dev server (gatsby develop) and they seem to render fine the first time when i run gatsby build and gatsby serve, but when I click refresh on them, my header and part of the rest of the site content gets cut off (as in, is not even available, there's no way to even scroll up to header and top content, it's simply not returned to the screen). I'm trying to figure out why this off behavior happens and why it only seems to appear in the production build. I don't see similar results in gatsby develop.

I had been building my site with a single page and a reach router set up for client side routing and thought that my routing (including having a not found page as default) was possibly causing issues, but removing that did not solve the issues. I had also created a fixed position header and thought maybe that was the issue but it didnt seem to fix it when i made the header relative and not fixed to the top of the screen.

I'd like to redirect this question to at least something I can describe accurately... when my page renders, it shows a div with CSS class called 'not-found' which is only meant to display when no route matches my router, but instead it wraps my valid components (e.g. dashboard) in this div for not-found even though that's not the intended design... and when i reload, i see a quick flash of the not-found page before the rest renders... i'd also not like 'not-found' to show up at all on valid pages... can you see anything in my structure that would lead to this?

My index.js gatsby page:

```
import React from "react";

import App from '../components/App';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {

        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'us-east-1',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: '***********',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
        userPoolWebClientId: '*******************'
    }
});


const IndexPage = () => (
    <div>
        <App>
            <Helmet>
                <title>Clean up your cloud</title>
            </Helmet>
        </App>
    </div>
)

export default IndexPage;
```

My app.js gatsby page:

```
import React from "react"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import Login from "../components/Login"
import SignUp from "../components/SignUp"
import PrivateRoute from "../components/PrivateRoute"
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard';
import RulesPage from '../components/RulesPage';
import AccountsPage from '../components/AccountsPage'
import Features from '../components/Features'
import Home from '../components/Home'
import Pricing from '../components/Pricing'
import SupportPage from '../components/SupportPage'
import Settings from '../components/Settings'
import Docs from '../components/Docs';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound';
import Users from '../components/Users';
import History from '../components/History';

import store from '../store'

const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Home path="/" />
            <PrivateRoute path="/app/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/app/rules" component={RulesPage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/app/accounts" component={AccountsPage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/app/users" component={Users} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/app/settings" component={Settings} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/app/support" component={SupportPage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/app/history" component={History} />
            <Login path="/app/login" />
            <SignUp path="/app/signup" />
            <Features path="/app/features" />
            <Pricing path="/app/pricing" />
            <Docs path="/app/docs" />
            <NotFound default />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
  )

  export default App;
```

Comment: Hi there! Would you share a [minimal, viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or at the very least the relevant code? As it is right now it's very difficult to tell what's wrong with your build.

Comment: @DerekNguyen yes completely agree that this is extremely vague... I will give some thought to how I can either provide the right code or minimal example later today... My project has grown big enough I'm a little unsure where the problem is in order even to provide the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for including additional code & welcome to Stackoverflow! I'm not sure what's going on, but the behavior you're describing [sounds a bit like what mentioned here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-prefixed-404-pages-for-different-languages/)

Comment: From the link above: "For best results, you should configure your server to serve these 404 pages in the same manner - i.e. for /en/<non existent path>, your server should serve the page /en/404/. Otherwise, you’ll briefly see the default 404 page until the Gatsby runtime loads."

Comment: since all of your routes are prefixed with /app/, would you try providing a `/app/` default page before <NotFound>?

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. I'll try that.

Comment: And yes long time Stackoverflow lurker, first time poster :)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, `gatsby develop` opens a `websocket` communication between your IDE/code editor and the browser, not building and assembling all assets at a glance, just the minimum to reproduce a work environment.

`gatsby develop` runs a server in the background, enabling useful features like live reloading and Gatsby’s data explorer. It is optimized for rapid feedback and extra debugging information.

Gatsby’s build command should be run when you’ve added the finishing touches to your site and everything looks great. `gatsby build` creates a version of your site with production-ready optimizations like packaging up your site’s config, data, and code, and creating all the static HTML pages that eventually get rehydrated into a React application. That process may cause a different behavior between both environments.

Something that works under `develop` (less strict) may not even compile in build mode due to webpack order issues.

You can check for further information (and a playground) in [Overview of Gatsby Build Process](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/#understanding-gatsby-develop-runtime).